# INotifyPropertyChanged gives error on frequent calls in silverlight c#

Tags: c#, silverlight, telerik, inotifypropertychanged, silverlight-5.0

I have created a base view model to put all common properties for all my view models into it and it is being implemented by all the view models of my C# Silverlight application.

My base view model also implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for all the view models.

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

When I frequently invoke the `PropertyChanged` event I get the error:

```
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

The stack trace is

```
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(IManagedPeerBase obj, DependencyProperty property, DependencyObject doh)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(IManagedPeerBase doh, DependencyProperty property, Object obj)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetObjectValueToCore(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Object newValue)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, ValueOperation operation)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, Boolean allowReadOnlySet, Boolean isBindingInStyleSetter)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.set_DefaultStyleKey(Object value)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl..ctor()
   at MS.Internal.CoreTypes.GetCoreWrapper(UInt32 typeId)
   at MS.Internal.ManagedPeerTable.EnsureManagedPeer(IntPtr unmanagedPointer, Int32 typeIndex, Type type, Boolean preserveManagedObjectReference)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.ConvertDO(IntPtr doPointer, Int32 typeIndex, Boolean releaseObjectReference)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.ConvertType(CValue outVal, Int32 typeIndex, Boolean releaseObjectReference, Boolean deleteBuffer, IManagedPeerBase fromObject)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.ConvertCValueForManagedWithType(Type propertyType, CValue& outVal, Int32 outDOType, Boolean releaseObjectReference, Boolean deleteBuffer, IManagedPeerBase fromObject)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.GetValue(IManagedPeerBase managedPeer, DependencyProperty property)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.GetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.get_Parent()
   at Telerik.Windows.RadRoutedEventHelper.FindParent(FrameworkElement item)
   at Telerik.Windows.RadRoutedEventHelper.BuildRoute(DependencyObject element, EventRoute route, RadRoutedEventArgs args)
   at Telerik.Windows.RadRoutedEventHelper.RaiseEvent(DependencyObject element, RadRoutedEventArgs args)
   at Telerik.Windows.DependencyObjectExtensions.RaiseEvent(DependencyObject element, RadRoutedEventArgs e)
   at Telerik.Windows.Controls.Selector.OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadComboBox.OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at Telerik.Windows.Controls.Selector.OnSelectionChanged(Object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at Telerik.Windows.Controls.Selector.SelectionChanger`1.InvokeSelectionChangedEvent()
   at Telerik.Windows.Controls.Selector.SelectionChanger`1.End()
   at Telerik.Windows.Controls.Selector.SelectionChanger`1.SelectJustThisItem(T item)
   at Telerik.Windows.Controls.Selector.SelectItemWithValue(Object value)
   at Telerik.Windows.Controls.Selector.CoerceSelectedValue(Object value)
   at Telerik.Windows.Controls.Selector.OnCoerceSelectedValue(DependencyObject sender, Object newValue)
   at Telerik.Windows.PropertyMetadata.DoCoercion(Func`3 areValuesEqual, DependencyObject d, DependencyProperty dp, CoerceValueCallback coerceCallback, Object defaultBaseValue, Boolean forceNewBaseValue, Boolean& isReentrantImplicitCoercion)
   at Telerik.Windows.PropertyMetadata.PropertyChangeHook.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.RaisePropertyChangeNotifications(DependencyProperty dp, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, ValueOperation operation)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.RefreshExpression(DependencyProperty dp)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SendDataToTarget()
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SourceAcquired()
   at System.Windows.Data.Debugging.BindingBreakPoint.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BreakOnSharedType>b__3()
```

Comment: Are you ever changing any property on a background thread?

Comment: no its always changed in ui thread

Comment: I think it might be related to Telerik control that you are using. Did you try contacting with tech support? Otherwise, you need to make a sample that can reproduce the issue. I have ViewModelBase with INP like you implemented as well but I have no problem so I think this issue might be related to the way that you bind or Telerik.

Comment: What property values are you setting? It looks to me like an invalid value is being set. I doubt it's down to the frequency of the calls.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't see anything wrong with your implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged, However I suspect somehow your code caused an infinite loop.

People might be able to help you out if you can shared a sample project that can reproduce the issue you have.